# Package Installation problem with pip (Python39)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I recently updated my Python version from 38 to 39 and changed my environment variables as well.

Now, when I'm trying to install packages using

```
pip install numpy
```

or

```
pip3 install numpy
```

I'm getting following error:

```
import pip._internal.utils.inject_securetransport  # noqa

ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I even tried reinstalling Python as well as changing the installation directory.

Can anyone provide any solution?
(PS: I'm using a Windows system)

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this issue happening for most pip commands.
The solution was reinstalling Python and pip, and make sure to uprade pip:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

if this doesn't work, it may be a problem with the ide or terminal.
Can you confirm if you can't use other pip commands? like uninstall or upgrade for example

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, running any command involving pip, I'm getting the same error